# Processing data in chunks with io.ReadFull results in corrupted file?

Tags: go, encryption, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to download and decrypt HLS streams by using `io.ReadFull` to process the data in chunks to conserve memory:

*Irrelevant parts of code has been left out for simplicity.*

```
func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create(out.ts)

    for _, v := range mediaPlaylist {
        resp, _ := http.Get(v.URI)
        for {
            r, err := decryptHLS(key, iv, resp.Body)
            if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
                break
            else if err != nil && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                panic(err)
            }
            io.Copy(f, r)
        }
    }
}

func decryptHLS(key []byte, iv []byte, r io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)

    buf := make([]byte, 8192)

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

        n, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                return nil, err
        }

    mode.CryptBlocks(buf, buf)

    return bytes.NewReader(buf[:n]), err
}
```

At first this seems to work as file size is correct and no errors during download,
but the video is corrupted. Not completely as the file is still recognized as a video, but image and sound is distorted.

If I change the code to use `ioutil.ReadAll` instead, the final video files will no longer be corrupted:

```
func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create(out.ts)

    for _, v := range mediaPlaylist {
        resp, _ := http.Get(v.URI)
        segment, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        r, _ := decryptHLS(key, iv, &segment)
        io.Copy(f, r)
    }
}

func decryptHLS(key []byte, iv []byte, s *[]byte) io.Reader {
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    mode.CryptBlocks(*s, *s)

    return bytes.NewReader(*s)
}
```

Any ideas why it works correctly when reading the entire segment into memory, and not when using `io.ReadFull` and processing it in chunks?

Comment: You're running a new `CBCDecrypter` with the initial `IV` for every 8K block. This is not how [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) works, the `IV` for `block n` is the ciphertext from `block n-1`. You should have only one `BlockMode` object for the entire file. You also need to check that you have full blocks.

Comment: I'd say the main reason would be the read chunks not necessarily correspond with the block size. I don't see the code handling this. . as well (as already commented) , you have to manage the correct IV and state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, CBCDecrypter makes a copy of your `iv`, so subsequent blocks start with the initial IV rather than the one that's been mutated by previous decryptions.

Create the decrypter once, and you should be able to keep re-using it to decrypt block by block (assuming the block size is a multiple of the block size expected by this crypto algorithm).